# Use "Fatos verídicos" (or "fatos reais") is redundant?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, redundâncias

When we are talking about some book or movie it's very common to see the following statements:

> - "Esse filme é baseado em fatos reais.";
> - "O livro foi feito com base em fatos verídicos.";

My question is: Is it redundant?

I already saw some arguments saying that a "fato"(fact) is always real, but I think that we can use "fato fictício" or something, so "fatos reais" is not redundant to me.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Note: "fato" is pt_BR and "facto" is pt_PT.

Comment: There are also _fatos surreais_. Is this a [_pleonasmo_](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pleonasmo)? Repetitions are frequently used to highlight a specific idea in several languages (real fact vs [true facts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249052/does-a-fact-have-to-be-true).

Comment: @JorgeB.  Hasn't the O.A. done away with the "c" in "facto"?

Comment: @Centaurus no, because fato is a suit on pt_PT: [Com o Acordo Ortográfico, escreve-se facto ou fato?](http://www.portoeditora.pt/espacolinguaportuguesa/duvidas-da-lingua-portuguesa/detalhe-duvidas-lp/ver/com-o-acordo-ortografico-escreve-se-facto-ou-fato-?id=22722)

Comment: `Fact` is like `Event` ... This is a event from chapter 46 of Harry Potter book... Harry Potter is not real :)

Comment: @Centaurus like Jorge points with the link, no, because we pronounce its c. We have fato (terno) and facto (fato), like we have [adição](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/adi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (soma) and [adicção](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/adic%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (dependência física, vício).

Comment: @ANeves  I see.  I know "fato" means "terno" in Portugal, and "guarda-fatos" means armário. What I didn't know was the word "adicção" (perhaps from the English "addiction") means "vício", "dependência física".

Comment: It's not common, here, either. I think it might be exclusively a medical term.

Answer (score 1):

Although there may be some redundancy, depending on how you define "fatos", "baseado em fatos reais" is a set phrase and means the same as "baseado em fatos verídicos".  **It's current usage and nobody stops to think whether it's redundant or not.**

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the meaning you are using for `fa(c)to`:

> **fac·to** |ct|
>
> (latim factum, -i, aquilo que se fez, façanha, proeza, acto)
>   *substantivo masculino*
>
> 1. Coisa realizada. = ACTO, FEITO
> 2. Acontecimento.
> 3. Sucesso.
> 4. Assunto (de que se trata).
> 5. Lance.
>
> "facto", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/facto [consultado em 08-01-2016].

If you add `real` to those definitions, only the first turns to look redundant: `coisa realizada real`.